# Calling quit in destructor doesn't kill the QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

I run this code through QtCreator.
Problem is that when I close the output window the thread doesn't die. To kill the thread I have to go to the terminal and kill it manually by finding its ID or use red square button on `Application output` window to kill it.

This application is supposed to be running forever unless we press Alt F4 to close the window.

**Source file [cpp]:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

Controller::Controller(QMainWindow *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    worker_obj.moveToThread(&workerThread);
    worker_obj.timerReceivePackets.moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(this, &Controller::operate, &worker_obj, &Worker::doSomething);

    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), &worker_obj, SLOT(initialize()));

    connect(&worker_obj, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);

    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), &workerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    workerThread.start();
}

Controller::~Controller()
{
    workerThread.wait();
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.terminate();
}
```

---

**Header [h]**

```
#ifndef Worker_H
#define Worker_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
public:

    QTimer timerReceivePackets;

    Worker(QObject * parent = 0) {}
    ~Worker() {}

public slots:
    void initialize()
    {
        connect (&timerReceivePackets, SIGNAL (timeout()),
                 this, SLOT (doSomething()));

        timerReceivePackets.start();
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            QString result;
                /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
            emit resultReady(result);
        }
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;

public:
    Worker worker_obj;

    Controller( QMainWindow *parent = 0 );
    ~Controller();

public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &) {}

signals:
    void operate(const QString &);

};

#endif // Worker_H
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. To start with, calling `deleteLater` (or binding it to a signal) on an object that is not directly allocated with `new` (as you do with the member subobject `workerThread`) is undefined behavior. Second, your `Controller` destructor looks like you're just randomly calling functions that kinda sound good without understanding how they would help you achieve your goal.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Please post an answer to show how to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is buried behind lots of other problems. I'm not rewriting all of your code.

Comment: Also, your `while(1)` loop won't let your thread quit.

Comment: @thuga I removed the while loop but still the thread doesn't quit.

Comment: Of course not. You're calling `wait` before you tell it to quit.

Comment: So, quite has to be called directly? I will try that. @thuga

Comment: Why does Qt's documentation tell us to wait after quit. That produced a seg fault in my case though. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html  . Search for this `workerThread.quit();` in that page please @thuga

Comment: Most likely because you've connected a signal to `deleteLater` as Sebastian pointed out.

Comment: @Thuga thanks for your patience

Comment: QWidget::closeEvent could be used for catching the close request from windowing system and thread could be asked to terminate (after adding possibility to break from the infinite loop in the thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution using [QWidget::closeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) to ask worker to finish its task. *Immediate window close* (application quit when main window is in question) *is ignored to terminate thread gracefully* and application is exited only after the worker has finished. This makes it possible to save the state of the expensive operation done in the thread before application is exited. After worker has finished `QObject::deleteLater` is called for worker, and `QThread::quit` for the thread which triggers deleteLater for the thread after it's fully shut down.

Controller:

```
class Controller : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Controller(QMainWindow *parent = nullptr)
        : QMainWindow(parent), m_worker(new Worker)
    {
        QThread *thread = new QThread;
        m_worker->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(thread, &QThread::started, m_worker, &Worker::operate);
        connect(m_worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        connect(m_worker, &Worker::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);
        connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(m_worker, &Worker::finished, m_worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(m_worker, &Worker::finished, qApp, &QApplication::quit);
        thread->start();
    }

    virtual ~Controller() {}

public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &result){
        qDebug() << result;
    }

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override
    {
        m_worker->finish();
        event->ignore();
    }

private:
    Worker *m_worker;
};
```

Worker:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent), m_continue(false) {}
    virtual ~Worker() {}

public slots:
    void operate(){
        m_continue = true;
        static QString result;
        while(m_continue)
        {
            result.append('a');
            QThread::sleep(2);
            emit resultReady(result);
        }
        emit finished();
    }

    void finish() {
        m_continue = false;
    }

signals:
    void finished();
    void resultReady(const QString &result);

private:
    bool m_continue;
};
```